# What does this circuit with an analog video signal to the emitter and a TX signal to the base of a an NPN do?

Tags: analog, cmos

The CAM1_AHD is the signal coming from a camera and it goes to the TVI receiver as well as to the emitter of the transistor. The video signaling scheme is analog. The TVI receiver is TP2825 and in the datasheet the pin 42 which is what the PTZ_TXD is connected to, says "Upstream data signal output. Unconnected when not used".

[image]

The TVI receiver is modeled as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: looks like some kind of amplifier, but the transistor terminals are mislabeled.

Comment: It's not a good design because it has no specs, Mismatched to 75 Ohms and attenuates >15dB  Why no specs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The video cable from camera is also used to transmit pan/tilt/zoom control data back to camera if it contains such a feature. The logic level TXD output data from the video receiver chip is buffered by the transistor which drives the video cable with AC coupled data signal.

Comment: Thank for the answer. What is the general name of such circuit?